# how to track the event when user click on edit control in mfc

Tags: mfc

thers is event onchngeedit for edit control but how to how to track the event when user click on edit control in mfc but doesn't change anything.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using onFocus() handler?  It will also pick up events when the user tabs into the control as well.